# Changing value of global variable in sub local function javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

There is no need the explain most of this code. As you can see the global variable `cancel` is set to true. Then a function is called in which the variable `cancel` is changed. ***It seems as though I can access the `cancel` variable on lines 15, 27, or 32.*** ***Can you explain why it doesn't work and how I can fix it?*** Thank you! Please ask any additional questions. I didn't explain the other code here because I don't think it pertains to the question directly and it would make this question too long to read if I were.

```
1. var cancel = 'true';
2. function setSliders()
3. {
4.  var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
5.  var sliderButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderButton');
6.  for(var i = 0; i != sliderButtons.length; i++)
7.  {
8.      var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderButton')[i];
9.      slider.onmousedown = function()
10.     {
11.         cancel = 'false';
12.         this.onmouseup = function(cancel)
13.         {
14.             cancel = 'true';
15.             alert(cancel +' within semi function cancel does not seem to be accessible here');
16.             //alert('test');
17.         };
18.         
19.         alert(cancel+' within function');
20.         
21.         this.onmousemove = function(event, cancel)
22.         {
23.             if(cancel == 'false')
24.             {
25.                 console.log('cancel is false'); //cancel doesn't seem to be accessible here either.
26.                 this.style.left = event.clientX+'px';
27.                 cancel = 'true';
28.             }
29.             else
30.             {
31.                 console.log('cancel is true'); //cancel isn't accessible here either.
32.                 cancel = 'false';
33.             }
34.         };
35.     };
```

Comment: You made it a parameter of callback function and it shadows the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `cancel` as argument name to your functions, making `cancel` within those functions be local to that function.

If you remove `cancel` from the arguments, it will reference the global `cancel` variable and should work.

```js
1. var cancel = 'true';
2. function setSliders()
3. {
4.  var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
5.  var sliderButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderButton');
6.  for(var i = 0; i != sliderButtons.length; i++)
7.  {
8.      var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderButton')[i];
9.      slider.onmousedown = function()
10.     {
11.         cancel = 'false';
12.         this.onmouseup = function()
13.         {
14.             cancel = 'true';
15.             alert(cancel +' within semi function cancel does not seem to be accessible here');
16.             //alert('test');
17.         };
18.         
19.         alert(cancel+' within function');
20.         
21.         this.onmousemove = function(event)
22.         {
23.             if(cancel == 'false')
24.             {
25.                 console.log('cancel is false'); //cancel doesn't seem to be accessible here either.
26.                 this.style.left = event.clientX+'px';
27.                 cancel = 'true';
28.             }
29.             else
30.             {
31.                 console.log('cancel is true'); //cancel isn't accessible here either.
32.                 cancel = 'false';
33.             }
34.         };
35.     };
```